# Foreach array of strings, each is upsert and increments to 1 but saves 2 on specific field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Good day,

I build api using node.js, express.js and the data is save to mongodb.

inside my route is

```
const { Tag } = require('../models/tag')

router.patch('/', async (req, res) => {
  const { tags } = req.body

  tags.forEach(async tag => {
    const filter = { name: tag }
    const option = { upsert: true }

    const update = { $inc: { commonality: 1 } }
    await Tag.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, option)
  });

  return res.json({})
})
```

Example

```
tags = [ 'blood', 'test']
```

But saves (commonality: 2) **weird happened here**.

```
    //document 1
    {
        "name" : "blood",
        "commonality" : 2
    }
    //document 2
    {
        "name" : "test",
        "commonality" : 2
    }
```

Instead of (commonality: 1)

```
    //document 1
    {
        "name" : "blood",
        "commonality" : 1
    }
    //document 2
    {
        "name" : "test",
        "commonality" : 1
    }
```

When a tag **by name field** already exists, I will just update the commonality of that existing tag increments to 1 step. Else, I will insert new document of tag with commonality of 1.

Is there something wrong with the looping? Because without a loop and only one tag, it works well. Or looping the awaitable save is not good idea? Your help is highly appreciated. Keep safe everyone.

Comment: Do you have tags as an array also and these objects also in the same doc? or are you trying to insert commonality for each tag?

Comment: Hi @Gibbs, yes I provided an example array og tags shown above and they come in same doc inside req.body. And I am trying to save an item when not exist with the value of one, else insert and increment the commonality to 1 step.

Comment: blood and test are part of array. Is it array of objects?

Comment: they are array of strings @Gibbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Problem is that array. You need to use `positional operator $`. Else all the elements will be updated in the array every time.

```
db.test.findOneAndUpdate({
  "tagData.name": "blood"
},{
    $inc: {"tagData.$.commonality":1}
})
```

You should something as above.

**Input doc:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0db1229e001b53e3995fde"),
    "tagData" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "blood",
            "commonality" : 2.0
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "test",
            "commonality" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

It will update the respective `commonality`

As in the code - as per OP suggestion - adding this

```
const update = { $inc: { [${tag}.$.commonality]: 1 } } 
//Specifying positional operator in the update part
```

Comment: using positional operator works, thanks a lot. I forgot and never thought about it. Can you update your answer only by this?   const update = { $inc: { [`${tag}.$.commonality`]: 1 } } then I will accept your answer.

Comment: @AljohnYamaro I am not a JS expert. I added it with a comment what I meant. Glad, it helped